# Nextgen Gallery - Every picture has its own gallery

Tags: wordpress

I want my 3 pictures to openup different galleries with lightbox when I click them. Is there anybody knows any way of doing it ?

Comment: Unaccepted the answer for one that states the same thing but in a much more vague way? What's your reasoning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating Album will solve your problem. There are also different options check out settings of nextgen gallery.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an Album for each of the 3 images. You can then place them inside the post using the TinyMce NextGen Gallery button and choose album with single image view. It's been a while since I've used Nextgen, so if you need more help let me know and I'll add it to one of my test sites so I can give more specific instructions.